# $.inArray issues with passing string from php script

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having a problem with the inArray function not sure why. I'm passing a string back to the Javascript from my PHP it looks something like this 22,24 ect. I've tried using the split command to convert it to a Javascript array and I've tried it just as is. Either way the inArray function isn't finding 22, I've tried 22 with and without speak marks in the inArray function.

```
$.ajax({
           url: "<?=base_url(); ?>/products/update_dropdown/"+<?=$product['product_id']?>+"/"+strUser,
           type: 'GET',
           success: function(msg) {
              var test;
              test = $.inArray(22, msg);
              alert(test);

            }

       });
```

Thank you for any help this is really driving me nuts!

Comment: I have just re-read your question and you mention attempting searching for `"22"` already so I have deleted my answer. Please supply the result of `console.log(msg);` so we can see what data the javascript is being passed. Also please show the data and code after you have attempted your split.

Comment: can you post the output of your query ?

Comment: Traffynnon console.log gets me 22,24 
Trikks test returns - 1

Comment: alexi not sure what you mean, sorry?

Comment: Traffynnon the result of the split is
["
22", "24"]

not sure why it's displaying on two lines... but that's what I get in the consloe.

Comment: @flyersun so the problem is the whitespace before the 22. You need to either trim this off before doing the comparison or use some regex.

Comment: @Traffynnon I tried searching for "24" as well though and still got the result of -1

Comment: @Traffynnon oh I think I see why now!

Comment: @flyersun Yes, I figured it out for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727813/inarray-issues-with-passing-string-from-php-script/5727852#5727852

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your comments it looks like the problem is that there is whitespace before the number 22 in your string (`[" 22", "24"]`).

You can run:

```
msg = msg.replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
test = $.inArray('22', msg);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/KAdRD/ for a worked example.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var test = "22,24,25";

 test = test.split(",")

 test = $.inArray(22+'', test); // explicitly convert search to string.
 alert(test);  // alerts index of found element.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s3X8V/1/

Comment: Exactly, it needs to be converted to an array before you ask it if it where! :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out, this would return 1 for a match, -1 for no match:

```
    var string = "33,34,35"; 
    var test = $.inArray("34",string.split(","));
    alert(test);
```

I'm guessing your return type may not be a string? Like the comment said try logging the variable or maybe the **typeof**

Comment: by return type I mean the **typeof** the **msg** variable may not be a string. Another possibility is that there may be whitespace around the string you are trying to split/search which could cause unexpected results

Comment: Thanks for the tip typeof come back with string so I don't know why it wasn't working. I've sorted it now anyways

Answer (score 1):

What about using indexOf function? If the variable set from PHP to JS is a string, you can use it this way:

```
if(msg.indexof('22', 0) != -1) {
    // this is the case when 22 is a part of msg...
} else {
    // this is the case when 22 is not present in msg...
}
```

Or is there any need of array from msg? Then I advise use of pure JS split() function:

```
test = msg.split(".");
```

Then You can call `$.inArray()`.

Comment: Sorted the problem before I got to try out this solution but thank you for the response.

Comment: No problem... Tried to help :]

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the value returned from php isn't an array in javascript. Its returned as a string.

```
$.ajax({
           url: "<?=base_url(); ?>/products/update_dropdown/"+<?=$product['product_id']?>+"/"+strUser,
           type: 'GET',
           success: function(msg) {
              var test;
              test = msg.search(/22/i)
              alert(test);

            }
       });
```

Or something like that

If you dont want to search string values you must split the msg string to an array and search the newly formed array instead.

Comment: Thank you that works perfect, I'm not bothered if a search a string or an array just as long as I get the result I want.

Comment: @Trikks @flyersun. Umm yeah but what if you get the number 222 or 221 in your arguments? The above code will match it and return true even if 22 is not actually in the string. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727813/inarray-issues-with-passing-string-from-php-script/5727852#5727852

Comment: @Trikks You do not need the `i` modifier in your regex by the way. Numbers are not case sensitive.

Comment: @flyersun this does not work in the way you think it does. See my comments above.

Comment: True, depending on the ranges of numbers you are to search for. I'd say redroot's solution is equally simple to to use. My point was simply that you return string values from your php page.

Comment: Perfect sorted:

                var test = msg;
                test = test.replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '');
                test = test.split(",")
                test = $.inArray("22", test);
                alert(test);

Comment: @flyersun That is the same answer as mine (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727813/inarray-issues-with-passing-string-from-php-script/5727852#5727852) you have there in your comment (except it is a poorer implementation). Not even an upvote? Seems a little mean.

Comment: @Treffynnon I'm sorry I hadn't actually seen you post at the bottom of the thread, I used Google to get the replace code. I've upvoved your answer now and marked and accepted your answer.

Comment: @Treffynnon also the thank you above was directed at you btw!